# Qt Concurrent with signals & slots

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

I'm a novice in threads and someone advises me to use Qt Concurrent (Qt C++).

I'm trying to run a function in a thread by using Qt Concurrent, my functions runs well but my signal/slot is never emitted.

However for your information if I launch my function without using thread everything works fine.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFutureWatcher<void> *watcher1 = new QFutureWatcher<void>();
    connect(watcher1, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(getSizeFinished()));

    QString string = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip";
    QFuture<void> future1 = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MainWindow::getRemoteFileSize, string);
    watcher1->setFuture(future1);
}

void MainWindow::getSizeFinished()
{
       qDebug() << "--- FINISHED ---";
}

void MainWindow::getRemoteFileSize(const QString &url)
{
    qDebug() << "Function - getRemoteFileSize";
    QNetworkRequest req;
    m_netmanager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    req.setUrl(QUrl(url));
    m_reply = m_netmanager->get(req);
    connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(metaDataChanged()), this, SLOT(remoteHTTPHeader()));
}

void MainWindow::remoteHTTPHeader()
{
    qDebug() << "Function - remoteHTTPHeader";
    remoteSize = m_reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader).toInt();
    qDebug() << "Remote File Size: " << remoteSize;
    m_reply->deleteLater();
    m_netmanager->deleteLater();
    qDebug() << "SIZE " << remoteSize;
}
```

Comment: Which signal is not called? Is every connection valid?

Comment: This one: connect(m_reply, SIGNAL(metaDataChanged()), this, SLOT(remoteHTTPHeader())); - remoteHTTPHeader is never called

Comment: Verify the connection is created correctly using `qDebug() << bool(connect(here your code))`, if it returns true it might be that the signal is not emitted for other reasons.

Comment: Yes it returns 'true'

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to create a connection in this case, you could call `MainWindow::remoteHTTPHeader()` right after `m_reply = m_netmanager->get(req);`.

You might want to check if the reply is effectively finished like so:

```
if (m_reply->isFinished()) {
    remoteHTTPHeader();
} else {
    connect(m_reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &MainWindow::remoteHTTPHeader);
}
```

This way you handle both fast and slow connections. Also notice how I created the connection using function pointers instead of `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macro, this syntax is better since it checks at compile time if the functions exist so you avoid making typos and the like.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I copy/paste your code I always go in the 'else' case. I also get a semantic error with the 'connect' : mainwindow.cpp:110:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'

Comment: Whoops, I left a parens that should have not been there, I fixed it. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Indeed, sorry I didn't notice it... thanks. However my function remoteHTTPHeader() is still never executed.

Comment: It's probably going to be executed only on really fast connection, if it's not of use you could remove it.

Comment: In my case users could have fast and very slow connection

Comment: I'd leave it there just in case then.